# Android save foreground dispatch on screen rotation

Tags: android, rotation, screen, nfc, screen-rotation

I setup a foreground dispatch like:

```
    mAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
        getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
mFilters = new IntentFilter[] { new IntentFilter(
        NfcAdapter.ACTION_TECH_DISCOVERED) };

// Setup a tech list for all NfcF tags
mTechLists = new String[][] { new String[] { MifareClassic.class
        .getName() } };
```

And i have:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();
mAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, mPendingIntent, mFilters,
        mTechLists);
}
```

But when screen rotates foreground dispatch stop calling public void onNewIntent(Intent intent).

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: When screen orientation changes activity is destroyed and recreated.

Comment: Ok, but....i only can call  enableForegroundDispatch() on onResume() action, so ... what i have to do to save the state or re-enable ForegroundDispatch on screen rotation?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html. Check onSavedInstanceState() and onRetainInstanceState()

Comment: ok, so i have to save the state of  NfcAdapter mAdapter between screen rotations. that's right?

Comment: yes. check the link posted in the comment for more information

Comment: No way, app stop scanning after screen rotation even using onSavedInstanceState() and onRetainInstanceState() for save NfcAdapter mAdapter state.

https://github.com/arrase/Mfc-Clone/blob/master/src/org/adictolinux/mfcclone/MainActivity.java

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am not familiar with nfc adapter but generally if you want save the state of primitives you do it in the methods mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your `mPendingIntent` contains a reference to the no-longer-existing previous instantiation of your Activity. Recreate the PendingIntent and things will probably start working as you intended.